# PHP Variables Are Always Null

Tags: php

I am trying to create a php login page, and capture the username and password input into html text boxes.  But my issue is that my echo statement always returns null for the variables.

Why are these variables not beting set?

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
  session_start();

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
      echo $myusername;
      echo $mypassword;
  }
?>
<html>   
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>      
  <style type = "text/css">
     body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     label {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     .box {
        border:#666666 solid 1px;
     }
  </style>      
   </head>   
   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">             
           <form action = "" method = "post">
              <label>UserName:</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
              <label>Passwore:</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
              <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
           </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
This is my config.php where I am using the `mysqli_connect()`

```
<?php
 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3036');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
 define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');
 $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your action param on the form has to be blank?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Blank action means to use the current URL as the action.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @Barmar - that shows me array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(2) "t1" }

Comment: If you haven't yet connected to the database, i.e. through mysqli_connect, then the  mysqli_real_escape_string function won't work. This is your problem.

Comment: Could you include the small bit where you post your variables to the page that you are currently showing? What kind of values are you posting? Does your posts hold any value at all?

Comment: @Chris I assume he's handling his connection in his include file? The `config.php`.

Comment: @Martin The variables are posted from the `<form>` at the bottom.

Comment: Turn on full warnings: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It sounds like there's a problem with `$db`, it doesn't contain a valid mysqli connection.

Comment: @Chris - see my edit where I posted my config.php.  I am initializing the mysqli_connect in that (or at least my limited php knowledge thinks I am)

Comment: You have an incorrect quote on the second `define` line. You have a curly quote instead of a straight quote.

Comment: Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: @Barmar - that was a copy/paste error.  I removed my username and password and dbname and I typed the '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a port number in the server name like that. It works for an external hostname, but it doesn't work when using `localhost`, according to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#121002) in the documentation. You need to use the optional port argument.

```
 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
 define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');
 define('DB_PORT', 3036);
 $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE,DB_PORT);
```

Comment: That was it - adding the port to it's own define has the code functioning as it should